# After a while in a session, commands to change one character change two. Why?

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

After vim has been open for a while (on Ubuntu in a console), I notice that commands start behaving differently. Mostly, they'll change or delete an extra character. For example:

```
123456
  ^ cursor here
```

Typing `dl` should delete the `3`, but instead deletes `34`.

Similarly, typing `s` should delete the `3` and take me into insert mode with the cursor over the `4`, but instead deletes `34` and takes me into insert mode with the cursor over the `5`.

I also notice sometimes that deleting a word will delete an extra character as well. For example:

```
hello world
^ cursor here
```

`de` should delete `hello` and place the cursor over the space, but instead would delete the space as well, with the cursor over the `w`.

What would cause this? Is there anything I can check, next time this happens, to debug it?

Here's my .vimrc, although it's long and references a bunch of plugins so I can't expect anyone to go through it for me: http://pastebin.com/z33b33E2

Comment: Start with the basics: disable your vimrc (`vim -Nu NONE`), if that works, try bisecting your plugins, etc.

Comment: @muru: unfortunately it doesn't seem to repro until being open for several hours at least -- some rare event must be triggering it, but I haven't narrowed it down. so it may take a month to bisect ;-)

Comment: What if you save the session, and restart the session? Tried different versions?

Comment: I didn't know you could save the session -- I'll give that a try next time and see what happens. I've just been quitting and starting over.

BTW, I edited to include my .vimrc: http://pastebin.com/z33b33E2

Comment: what does `omap l`show?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: "No mapping found". It isn't just `l` in particular so I doubt any one key is mapped incorrectly. Seems more like there's a setting that gets flipped or something.